# throw an error if the input date is greater than today

Tags: javascript, html, date

I am having an input date field in my php/html page. In my date field i need to throw an error if the input date is greater than today (sysdate). Is it possible? if so please help.
Here is my html script of input field. Another JavaScript is also working based on the input date to the field to identify the due date automatically.

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group col-sm-4">
<div class="input-group-addon">Transaction Date&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
<input id ="txndt" class="form-control" type="date" name ="purch_date" onblur = "txn40();" required />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using some calendaring library?

Comment: You should post your javascript. Also `date` is not a valid input type

Comment: @DarkBee [Get with HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Attributes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked with java script also. I have called a java script from my 'form'. Here is the solution.It is working as expected by me.

Form

```
<form  name="purchase" id ="purchase" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return checkform()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group col-sm-4">
            <div class="input-group-addon">Transaction Date&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                <input id ="txndt" class="form-control" type="date" max="<?php echo date("Y-m-d")?>" name ="purch_date" value="<?php echo $query2['purch_date'] ?>" onblur = "txn40();" required />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Java Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkform()
    {
    var dateString = document.purchase.txndt.value;
    var myDate = new Date(dateString);
    var today = new Date();
         if (document.purchase.txndt.value == "")
          { 
          //something is wrong
          alert('REQUIRED FIELD ERROR: Please enter date in field!')
          return false;
          }
          else if (myDate>today)
          { 
          //something else is wrong
            alert('You cannot enter a date in the future!')
            return false;
          }
          // if script gets this far through all of your fields
          // without problems, it's ok and you can submit the form
          return true;
    }
</script>
```

Thanks to all for support.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the `valueAsDate` property against the current date.

```
document.querySelector('#txndt').onchange = function() {
    if (this.valueAsDate > new Date) {
        alert("You can't pick a future date!")
    }
};
```

Comment: I have tried to restrict this in the input level itself with the max function. (type="date" max="2014-11-02"). is there any possibility to set the max as sysdate?

Comment: I'm not sure `max` works with `type="date"`. This essentially sets the max to the current date, by giving an error if you change it above. If you want, you could change the `alert` to `return false` to stop the value from changing at all.

Comment: Yes, its worked with max. I have done this:  type="date" max="<?php echo date("Y-m-d")?>". Its working as expected.

Comment: If you have an answer to your question, [feel free to post it as an answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: thanks for the support. But I have also tried to block the future date input by using the provided script, because heard that the max function will not support in some browsers. But the script is not working in my form. I have just copied and pasted the provided script, is anything more to do?

Comment: If you're using a script, you should add that to the question.

Comment: sorry. I have used the script provided by you as answer. that is why i didnt added again. Here is it. I have only added this in the beginning <script type="text/javascript"> and 
</script> at the end. I am not familiar with java script, thats why asking.

Answer (score 0):

Worked with 'max' function and 'php'. Working fine in chorome browser (HTML 5 supported browser). Changed the input with the below one.

```
<input id ="txndt" class="form-control" type="date" max="<?php echo date("Y-m-d")?>" name ="purch_date" onblur = "txn40();" required />
```